# Docker Mac Beta and container connecting to host ports?

Tags: python, macos, intellij-idea, docker, docker-compose

I currently use PyCharm (Actually IntelliJ) and have been using Kitematic with VirtualBox support.

I have a container connecting to the host (which is a virtual machine) to do remote debugging.

The issue is when I try to use Docker Mac Beta, the container doesn't seem to be able to access any specific ports on the host but it can ping the host. Which doesn't make any sense...

Anyone have any ideas?

Is there some magic sauce I need to make the python debugger listen on all IPs/Ports maybe?

Edits:

To clarify, when running a python script in this environment, the script has to initiate an outbound connect to a specified ip/port.

Here's some console output to help understand:

This is inside the container itself. I have the debugger running on port 15001 on my Mac.

```
# /sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'
172.17.0.1
# ping 172.17.0.1
PING 172.17.0.1 (172.17.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.078 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.066 ms
^C--- 172.17.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.066/0.072/0.078/0.000 ms
# telnet 172.17.0.1 15001
Trying 172.17.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
#
```

And then on the host (my mac):

```
➜   telnet localhost 15001
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying fe80::1...
telnet: connect to address fe80::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
501 1   0.1 UNIX
```

This all works fine with the old virtualbox based Docker setup, which makes sense since its using full fledge virtual machines. But not sure how the new Docker Beta works, especially when it comes to networking.

I am using Docker-Compose for this, so I can set up the networking through the network configuration options but so far, I haven't gotten any random attempts to work.

Also, the container is able to access anything else (google.com or whatever), just not a specific port on the host machine.

Comment: Shouldn't the host be trying to access ports on the container? Not vice-versa?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail what you mean by "the host (which is a virtual machine)"? In any case, when you have multiple layers like this, you want to use a specific IP and make sure that IP is shared/bridged by the source and target machines.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you need to expose port 15001.

Try adding to Dockerfile

EXPOSE 15001

Answer (score 0):

Create a host-based loopback device and then use a remote_host alternative (like in xdebug) to configure your container to connect back to that host ( on the port ), this will solve your issue as it does for PHP ( same issue ). We had the same case when switching from dockertoolbox to docker for mac. See a configuration example including the launchdaemon to create the host loopback interface here: https://gist.github.com/EugenMayer/3019516e5a3b3a01b6eac88190327e7c